# Windbg with SOS, How to dump a c# struct

Tags: c#, .net, struct, windbg, sos

How do I dump a struct using windbg, is there a dumpstruct command similar to dumpobject? Or can dumpobject dump structs aswell?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you could use the `!dumpvc` command.
Since structs don't have an object header, the debugger doesn't know its type, so you will have to pass it the struct's `MethodTable` address.

```
>!DumpVC <METHOD_TABLE_ADDRESS> <OBJECT_ADDRESS>
```