# Windgb with SOS does not show struct field values

Tags: c#, .net, windbg, sos

I'm trying to debug a running ASP.NET app with WinDbg. What I need is to see the value of an argument passed to a method. So I'm on a breakpoint in this method, and from `!clrstack -p` i get this:

```
PARAMETERS:
    this (0x00000004af4fdc10) = 0x000001a2b8a06e68
    ideaForum (0x00000004af4fdc18) = 0x000001a2b8b11bc8
    page (0x00000004af4fdc20) = 0x0000000300000001
```

I'm interested in the "page" argument which is of type `int?`(`System.Nullable<System.Int32>`) so first I find the MT address for `` System.Nullable`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib]] `` which happens to be 00007ffa263c7ae0. Then I call `!dumpvc 00007ffa263c7ae0 0000000300000001` and here is what I get:

```
Name:        System.Nullable`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib]]
MethodTable: 00007ffa263c7ae0
EEClass:     00007ffa25dc6580
Size:        24(0x18) bytes
File: C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll

Fields:
              MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr            Value Name
00007ffa263da2e0  4000707        0       System.Boolean  1 instance  hasValue
00007ffa263baf60  4000708        4         System.Int32  1 instance  value
```

As you can see, I'm doing what was marked as answer in [Windbg with SOS, How to dump a c# struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717292/windbg-with-sos-how-to-dump-a-c-sharp-struct) but it doesn't display values for fields which is what I need. What else do I need to do to get to the values?
Thanks.

EDIT: It appears I was using the wrong address for the argument after all. The one in parens after the argument name is the correct one, so I should have used `0x00000004af4fdc20`. With this, !dumpvc does work as expected. Sosex is easier to use because it just needs the argument name to do the job

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `!sosex.mk -a`. Use `!mdt` for dumping types, if what you are after is field values. Sosex tends to be more friendly at displaying field values, whereas sos excels in displaying the more technical details of layout. Disclosure: I am the author of sosex, but it is completely free.

Comment: Thank you Steve, ```!sosex.mdt page``` did the trick. I love the sosex help pages btw!

Comment: I'm glad it is useful to you.